# Power Query: Change Header Titles from Camel Case to Snake Case

Tags: powerquery

I have just imported some data into Power Query.  The headers are in camel case.  I.e.:

- headerOne
- headerTwo
- headerThree
- Etc.

I would like them to be in snake case.  I.e.:

- header_one
- header_two
- header_three
- Etc.

I am not sure, though, how to do this.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Examine the applied steps to understand the algorithm.

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],

//change column headers
    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    #"Split at UpperCase" = List.Transform(colNames,  each Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"a".."z"},{"A".."Z"})(_)),
    #"Snake Case" = List.Transform(#"Split at UpperCase", each Text.Lower(Text.Combine(_,"_"))),
    rename = Table.RenameColumns(Source, List.Zip({colNames,#"Snake Case"}))

in
    rename
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to replace "X" with "_x" for any upper-case letter.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSlTSUUoC4mSl2FgA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [headerOne = _t, headerTwo = _t, headerThree = _t]),
    Headers = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    NewHeaders = List.Transform(Headers, each Text.Combine(List.Transform(Text.ToList(_), each if List.Contains({"A".."Z"}, _) then "_" & Text.Lower(_) else _))),
    Result = Table.RenameColumns(Source, List.Zip({Headers, NewHeaders}))
in
    Result
```

This splits each header into a list of characters (using `Text.ToList`), replaces any capital letter in "A" to "Z" with the "_" prepended to the lower-case version (using `List.Transform`), and then combines the list back into a string (using `Text.Combine`).